# Georeferencer negative impact on image resolution

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, georeferencing, resolution

I added CRS to my .tif image(it weights 120gb and doesnt have CRS) using QGIS gdal method (Georeferencer). And the result .tif image with CRS (EPSG:4326) weights 70gb and image resolution is much lower.
What can I do to make .tif image georeferenced without losing resolution?

gdalinfo no CRS image:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: E:/UniversalMapDownloader/belarus15tiff/belarus15tiff.tif
       E:/UniversalMapDownloader/belarus15tiff/belarus15tiff.tif.ovr
       E:/UniversalMapDownloader/belarus15tiff/belarus15tiff.tif.aux.xml
Size is 224000, 193536
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (2579291.082095947116613,7615221.605768660083413)
Pixel Size = (4.777314267158510,-4.871598120393480)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2579291.082, 7615221.606) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Left  ( 2579291.082, 6672391.992) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Upper Right ( 3649409.478, 7615221.606) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Right ( 3649409.478, 6672391.992) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      ( 3114350.280, 7143806.799) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Band 1 Block=224000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=85.771, StdDev=39.436
  Overviews: 112000x96768, 56000x48384, 28000x24192, 14000x12096, 7000x6048, 3500x3024, 1750x1512, 875x756, 438x378, 219x189
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=85.770927113703
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=39.435701516509
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 2 Block=224000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=94.877, StdDev=35.592
  Overviews: 112000x96768, 56000x48384, 28000x24192, 14000x12096, 7000x6048, 3500x3024, 1750x1512, 875x756, 438x378, 219x189
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=94.876524173955
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=35.591944595646
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 3 Block=224000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=85.921, StdDev=39.478
  Overviews: 112000x96768, 56000x48384, 28000x24192, 14000x12096, 7000x6048, 3500x3024, 1750x1512, 875x756, 438x378, 219x189
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=85.921192267979
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=39.477874066998
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

gdalinfo for image with CRS:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: E:/UniversalMapDownloader/belarus15tiff/belarus15tiff_modified.tif
       E:/UniversalMapDownloader/belarus15tiff/belarus15tiff_modified.tif.ovr
Size is 263321, 135256
Origin = (23.170182095865464,56.247114940754820)
Pixel Size = (0.000036506977243,-0.000036506977243)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  23.1701821,  56.2471149) 
Lower Left  (  23.1701821,  51.3093272) 
Upper Right (  32.7832359,  56.2471149) 
Lower Right (  32.7832359,  51.3093272) 
Center      (  27.9767090,  53.7782211) 
Band 1 Block=263321x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 131661x67628, 65831x33814, 32916x16907, 16458x8454, 8229x4227, 4115x2114, 2058x1057, 1029x529, 515x265, 258x133
Band 2 Block=263321x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 131661x67628, 65831x33814, 32916x16907, 16458x8454, 8229x4227, 4115x2114, 2058x1057, 1029x529, 515x265, 258x133
Band 3 Block=263321x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 131661x67628, 65831x33814, 32916x16907, 16458x8454, 8229x4227, 4115x2114, 2058x1057, 1029x529, 515x265, 258x133
```

Comment: Please add gdalinfo about the original and the georeferenced image.

Comment: The original image is georeferenced but the coordinate reference system is wrong. CRS EPSG:4326 does not match with the corner coordinates `Upper Left  ( 2579291.082, 7615221.606)...`. Better than to use the georeferencer is to find out what is the real CRS of the source data and correct the image metadata.

Comment: thank you. But how can i find real CRS?

Comment: If you have harvested the image from some common web service with https://www.allmapsoft.com/umd/ it is the CRS that the map site is using, probably EPSG:3857.